# Navigation Bar in a View Controller (is this allowed?)

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, viewcontroller

With StoryBoards inserting the Navigation Bar into a View Controller page is easy, you just do it. But how do I alter the Navigation Bar title?

Is this because you're not allowed to put a Nav Bar in a View Controller and if so what's the work around?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are asking... I just dragged a new View Controller from the Object Library onto a storyboard, then dragged a Navigation Bar (also from the library) onto the new View Controller, and it had the word "Title" already there when it appeared.  I can double click the word Title and change it to whatever string I want.  Is that what you did?  And you're saying it didn't have the "Title" placeholder there automatically?

Comment: That's exactly it, it's too easy to do. The question is how do you alter the Title programatically, say in viewDidLoad? I suspect that the ViewController class is a sub-class of the Naviation Controller. So how do you alter the title via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the title in a UIViewController programmatically, there is a `setTitle:` method.  You can call it by
 `[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Whatever is in these quotes will be my title"];`

or if you have an

```
NSString *myTitleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Whatever is in these quotes will be my title"];
```

you just need

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:myTitleString];
```

You can use these methods just about anywhere in your UIViewController's .m file, probably in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:animated` or `initWithStyle:style`.

Comment: No, they're not working. Remember I have placed the Navigation Bar at the top of a View Controller page. What next?

Comment: You might need to make your view controller a navigation controller delegate for this to work.  In your view controller's .h file, at the end of the line that starts with `@interface`, add `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>`.  If there is already something there, just add a comma and the nav delegate statement, so it would be like `<somethingElseDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>`.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Another way to get a new page in the Navigation Controller list is to just do a "push" segue from a view already in the Navigation Controller.  So if you already have dropped a Navigation Controller onto your storyboard, it brings a UITableViewController with it.  If you want a normal UIView (without the table), you can just delete the UITableViewController, drag in a new UIViewController, and control-drag from the Navigation Controller to the new UIViewController, and select "root view Controller". (character limit...)

Comment: To add a second view to the Navigation Controller chain, drag a second UIViewController onto your storyboard, and control-drag from your first UIVIewController (NOT THE NAVIGATION CONTROLLER!!) to the second UIViewController and select a "push" segue.  There will be a little link icon that appears between the first and second UIViewControllers - click that and set it's "Identifier" property (to any string you want) in the Attributes Inspector.  You can then preform that transition in your code using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier"@"string from Identifier property here" sender:self];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might also be the way you added the UIViewController to the project.  Instead of dropping a View Controller onto your storyboard, then a Navigation Bar onto the View Controller, try dropping just a Navigation Controller.  When you drop the navigation controller, it will automatically bring a View Controller with it and automatically put the Navigation Bar on the View Controller it brings.

Then, as in my other answer, add `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>` to the .h file you link to your new View Controller, and use `[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"My Title"]` in your `viewDidLoad` to set the title.

Comment: I am certain you are right. The current cut of xcode not only drops a Navigation Controller onto the Storyboard but also a Root View Controller with a Table View embedded. This might be my misunderstanding of the Navigation Controller thinking that it's a View set up with Navigation preprogrammed into it, rather than being a controlling page. I think I can get this to work. The only problem is that I have a number of pages daisy chained together and how do I add the additional pages to the Nav Controller...

Comment: The Navigation Controller is a controller that manages subsequent pages. If you decouple the link from the Nav Controller to the Table View in Xcode samples all you get is a title bar. What I need to know is how you legitimately create a page with a Navigation Bar at the top of it.

Comment: Sorted - they altered the way the Nav Controllers work from Xcode 3 to 4. Slap a Page View on the Storyboard and then from the menus go Editor/Embed In/Navigation Controller. Now all your kind advice will work.